# How to handle multiple URL patterns. Any pattern order leads to 404 for different pages

Tags: django, django-urls

I need your help.
There was a problem with the url, the structure is as follows:

- the main project file urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('', include('shop.urls')),
    path('', include('informations.urls')),
]
```

- shop.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('contact', views.Contact, name="contact"),
    path('<str:category_slug>/', views.TireListByCategory, name='category_list'),
    path('pdf/<int:id>/', views.render_pdf_detail_view, name='test-pdf-view'),
    path('pdf/category/<str:category_slug>/', views.render_pdf_category_view, name='category_pdf_list'),
    path('brand/<str:slug>/', views.BrandDetail, name='brand_detail'),
    path('<str:category_slug>/<str:slug>/', views.TireDetail, name='tire_detail'),
    path('brands/<str:brand_slug>/<str:slug>/', views.BrandModelDetail, name='brand_model_detail'), 
]
```

- informations.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', views.page_info_blog, name='page_info_blog'),
    path('<str:category_info_slug>/', views.category_info_detail, name='category_info_detail'),
    path('<str:category_info_slug>/<str:page_info_slug>/', views.page_info_detail, name='page_info_detail')
]
```

The first include('shop.urls') works fine
The second is a 404 error
Also, when replacing places, only the first one on the list works, the second one is a 404 error

Please tell me about the level urls.  M

I change places, then only the first one on the list works.  The second throws a 404 error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp6yo.jpg)

Comment: Please ask the question in *English* or at [ru.SO].

Comment: What exact endpoints result in 404? / Які саме вʼюхи призводять до 404 помилки?

Comment: @Bohdan - added a screenshot to the post

Comment: Question: Why should `blog/` and `<str:category_info_slug>/` not be captured by `<str:category_slug>/` similarly for other urls. And also how should Django figure this out? Your URL patterns are effectively the same so Django just uses the first matching URL.